# Python Image Window Not Closing Properly on Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pycharm

I'm working with OpenCV and trying to figure this out. When I want to read and show an image:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('baboon.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('image')
```

I write this. But whenever the image display window pops up, I'm not able to close it and execute everything after

```
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('image')
```

because the window will not close unless I quit it.

For example, if I run this code

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('baboon.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('image')
#Nothing after this will get executed
print('Hello')
```

I get no output in my console, but the image window does pop up.

How can I fix this?

(I'm using Pycharm if that helps)

EDIT:

It seems that whenever I press **any** key the window closes and it works as intended (code after the comment is executed). Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: how are you quitting it? are you pressing a key or ctrl+c?

Comment: I'm pressing the red quit button at the top of the window.

Comment: what happens when you just press a key, any key

Comment: I just edited the original post.

Comment: I believe the quit is acting as a keyboard interrupt, which quits the entire python program. This is different than pressing a key, which is incorporated into the logic of the actual program and continues to completion.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you! Would you mind putting this into an answer so I can mark that as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the quit is acting as an interrupt, which quits the entire python program. This is different than pressing a key, which is incorporated into the logic of the actual program and continues to completion:

```py
cv2.waitKey(0) # waits for any key to be pressed to continue the logic of the program
# this is what actually allows you to "display" an image without it immediately disappearing.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can click on anywhere in the pic and it would return to the code window